# logstash assign values to variable and execute perl script

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to assign "actor":"githubuser"  like  $actor = "gituser"  and $repo = "gituser/logstashreppo", If I get the values assgined to variables , I can execute my script using exec function copied here. Please share your thoughts

whole output is

```
{
_index: "logstash-2014.11.20",
_type: "syslog",
_id: "76ggV_gfWS5u2L9rcMNCWaQ",
_score: 0.35005248,
_source: {
message: "github_audit: {"actor_ip":"192.168.1.1","from":"repositories#create","actor":"gituser","repo":"gituser/logstashreppo","action":"staff.repo_route","created_at":1236483708817,"repo_id":44758,"actor_id":1033,"data":{"actor_location":{"location":{"lat":null,"lon":null}}}}",
@version: "1",
@timestamp: "2014-11-17T11:41:50.142Z",
host: "192.168.1.1",
type: "syslog",
syslog5424_pri: "190",
timestamp: "Nov 17 03:41:50",
actor_ip: "192.168.1.1",
from: "repositories#create",
actor: "gituser",
repo: "gituser/logstashrepo",
action: "staff.repo_route",
created_at: 1236483708817,
repo_id: 44758,
actor_id: 1033,
data: {
actor_location: {
location: {
lat: null,
lon: null
}
}
}
}
}
```

,

my config file is :

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [
      "message",
      "%{SYSLOG5424PRI}%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:host} %{GREEDYDATA:message}"
    ]
    overwrite => ["host", "message"]
  }
  if [message] =~ /^git_audit: / {
    grok {
      match => ["message", "^git_audit: %{GREEDYDATA:json_payload}"]
    }
    json {
      source => "json_payload"
      remove_field => "json_payload"
    }
mutate {
  rename => ["[json][repo]", "repo"]
  remove_field => "json"
}
  }
}

input {
exec {
    type => "audit-log"
    command => "perl test.pl $actor"

  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: You posted invalid JSON with an unterminated string. Check quotes escaping. See also: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of exactly what you want in the [exec plugin's documentation](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/exec).

```
exec {
    type => "audit-log"
    command => "perl test.pl %{actor}"
}
```

See also the ["sprintf format" section in the documentation of the configuration file format](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/configuration#sprintf), but note that the `%{fieldname}` syntax doesn't work inside all strings (and it's not well documented where it works and where it doesn't).

Finally, note that the `type` attribute is deprecated for output plugins like exec. You should rewrite it like this:

```
if [type] == "audit-log" {
    exec {
        command => "perl test.pl %{actor}"
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I can execute the script inside, however, I am looking for particular three values from output I pasted my question ,  once I get those three values separately , I'll pass those values to my script in the perl execution part  ( I am actually looking for these three values from  output I pasted my question              (from: "repositories#create",
    actor: "gituser",
    repo: "gituser/logstashrepo",)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Do you want to run the script only if actor is "gituser", repo is "gituser/logstashrepo" etc?

Comment: I actually expecting 'gituser' and 'gituser/logstashrepo' output only from the whole output(I've copied whole output in my initial question) and I'll execute my perl script using those two values, thanks in Advance

Comment: So you _only_ want those three fields extracted from the JSON object? Fine, but that's a _completely_ different question (that I thought I answered a couple of days back – have the 'json' filter store the results in a subfield, move the fields you want to save into the top level, and delete the subfield).

Comment: thanks for all your help, since I am new this setup, I was able to bring on the top, however, I can't assign those fields to any variable . i am looking for extracting those three fields only from the output and assign to variable for perl script input.  thanks Again

Comment: Sorry, I give up. Your question just isn't clear to me.

Comment: Hi, sorry, if I am not clear, I am looking for one value only from output pasted above (actor: "gituser" only)  and I need to send the value to this exec  ( exec {
    type => "audit-log"
    command => "perl test.pl %{actor}"
}